# How do I check if a list of Bool value contain the same value?

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I want to write a function like:

```
sameBool :: [Bool] -> Bool
```

for example:

```
[True, False, True] => False
[True, True] => True
```

Here's my solution:

```
sameBool :: [Bool] -> Bool
sameBool xs = if head xs == True
                  then length (filter (== False) xs) == 0
                  else length (filter (== True)  xs) == 0
```

Effective though not elegant. I'm looking for some more elegant solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [all](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all):

```
sameBool :: [Bool] -> Bool
sameBool xs = all (== head xs) xs
```

With [nub](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) from `Data.List`:

```
import Data.List

sameBool :: [Bool] -> Bool
sameBool = (== 1) . length . nub
```

Actually, they works for any instance of `Eq`:

```
sameBool :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
sameBool xs = all (== head xs) xs
-- Note: return True for []

sameBool :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
sameBool = (== 1) . length . nub
-- Note: return False for []
```

Check [nubBy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nubBy) for types that aren't instances of `Eq`.

Comment: Instead of `(==1) . length` I would use `null . drop 1`, because it is lazier. That is it doesn't have to walk the whole list if it already found a `True` and a `False`. Note that this change will also return `True` for `[]` instead of `False`, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: Wow. One of the rare cases where `head xs` will not error out on the empty list. It took a few seconds to me to realize that it was indeed safe :-)

Comment: @jpath His own code trigger exception on an empty list

Comment: @chi 2 `sameBool` return differently for `[]`

Comment: *allSame* means *noneDifferent*, so `sameBool []` *must* be `True`.